# WebAPI Filter to convert response to CSV

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, csv, asp.net-web-api

Is there a way to connect a filter to a WebAPI response to convert a normal JSON response into a .csv (text/csv) response?

I have several reports that call out to a ReportsController (ApiController) for JSON data to populate the reports. I would love it if I could convert that data to .csv and navigate users into the GET url via a window.open() call or href.

I have not done filters before. Where did I begin? Anyone work on something like this before?

Comment: I think WebAPI only allows you to return JSON or XML, not a file. You can do it in a regular MVC Controller by returning a FileResult from an action method.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is relatively old but the way to go would be to write a `MediaTypeFormatter`. See [this tutorial](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/media-formatters) for an explanation.